# Hierarchical training for doc2vec: how would assigning same labels to sentences of the same document work?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

What is the effect of assigning the same label to a bunch of sentences in doc2vec? I have a collection of documents that I want to learn vectors using gensim for a "file" classification task where file refers to a collection of documents for a given ID. I have several ways of labeling in mind and I want to know what would be the difference between them and which is the best -

- Take a document d1, assign label `doc1` to the tags and train. Repeat for others
- Take a document d1, assign label `doc1` to the tags. Then tokenize document into sentences and assign label `doc1` to its tags and then train with both full document and individual sentences. Repeat for others

For example (ignore that the sentence isn't tokenized) -

```
Document -  "It is small. It is rare" 
TaggedDocument(words=["It is small. It is rare"], tags=['doc1'])
TaggedDocument(words=["It is small."], tags=['doc1'])
TaggedDocument(words=["It is rare."], tags=['doc1'])
```

- Similar to above, but also assign a unique label for each sentence along with `doc1`. The full document has the all the sentence tags along with `doc1`.

Example -

```
Document -  "It is small. It is rare" 
TaggedDocument(words=["It is small. It is rare"], tags=['doc1', 'doc1_sentence1', 'doc1_sentence2'])
TaggedDocument(words=["It is small."], tags=['doc1', 'doc1_sentence1'])
TaggedDocument(words=["It is rare."], tags=['doc1', 'doc1_sentence2'])
```

I also have some additional categorical tags that I'd be assigning. So what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this! Assigning the same tag to multiple texts has *almost* the same effect as would combining those texts into one larger text, and assigning it that tag. The slight differences would be for `Doc2Vec` modes where there's a context-window – PV-DM (`dm=1`). With separate texts, there'd never be contexts stretching across the end/beginning of sentences.

In fact, as `gensim`'s optimized code paths have a 10,000-token limit to text sizes, splitting larger documents into subdocuments, but repeating their tags is sometimes necessary as a workaround.

What you've specifically proposed, training both the full-doc, and the doc-fragments, would work, but also have the effect of doubling the amount of text (and thus training-attention/individual-prediction-examples) for the `'doc1'` tags, compared to the narrower per-sentence tags. You might want that, or not - it could affect the relative quality of each.

What's best is unclear - it depends on your corpus, and end goals, so should be determined through experimentation, with a clear end-evaluation so that you can automate/systematize a rigorous search for what's best.

A few relevant notes, though:

- `Doc2Vec` tends to works better with docs of at least a dozen or more words per document.
- The `'words'` need to be tokenized - a list-of-strings, not a string.
- It benefits from a lot of varied data, and in particular if you're training a larger model – more unique tags (including overlapping ones), and many-dimension vectors – you'll need more data to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't particularly understand what you mean by the effect of doubling the text and "training-attention/individual-prediction-examples"? Will it lead to overfitting?

Comment: Overfitting is mainly a risk if you have a large model (in total number of tunable parameters, which here are essentially word/doc vectors) and relatively small data. But also, you can't turn small data into large data by just repeating it. (If you have just 2 unique documents, it doesn't become as good as 2 million docs by repeating them each a million times.) If you supply 2 tags for a doc, it's a bit like supplying the document twice, once with one tag, and once with another. In fact, in PV-DBOW mode (`dm=0`), that's exactly how it works. …

Comment: In PV-DM modes (`dm=1`), two tags on the same doc aren't quite that way – but your proposed approach of "feed the text once whole, then again split up as sentences where the sentences have two tags" again means the '`doc1'` tag gets involved in twice as many individual target-word-predictions ("individual-prediction-examples") during training, compared to either (1) just training on the full doc; or (2) just training on the dual-tagged sentences. So in a sense it's getting more effort applied to it. That might be good or bad depending on your needs. …

Comment: Illustrative example: if some docs seem especially important, you could consider repeating just them, & leave other docs to appear once, The repeated docs would thus affect the model more. Or, consider that if docs have wildly different word-lengths, they get imbalanced training effort. (A 100-word-doc lets model try to predict its 100 words, thus 100 model nudges per training pass; a 10-word doc only 10.) You could try to overweight small docs, by repeating them, or underweight longer docs (perhaps by randomly dropping words), to try to even their influence on the model & vector quality. …

Comment: (I give those examples as illustrations of effect, not specific recommendations. But if you did get to a point where you noticed, for example, that full-doc vectors are good but the sentences bad, or long-doc-vectors good and short-doc-vectors bad, you could consider experimenting with such variants.)

Comment: Thanks, really helps. So I had a question about having the same categorical tags. Say, I have 3 docs with the first two having a category of 'action' and the other 'romance' for an unrelated classification task (not classifying genre). Would having action and romance as additional tags for these documents help, ie, will it learn a more "discriminative" embedding between action and romance docs? I know this is a bit of a vague question and it'll depend on the task but I wanted to know how exactly is a document vector affected by the presence of one of its categorical tags in another document.

Comment: You'd have to try it, it depends on so many particulars of the corpus/settings/goals/etc. I've seen cases where adding known categories helped make the resulting doc-vectors work a little better for a downstream classifier. But then other times I've tried it, I didn't see the boost. There might be a sweet spot in relative granularity-of-categories compared to corpus size, or unique-doc-ID-tags, or model size, or other factors. (Re-inferring single doc-vectors at the end, for texts which had multiple tags during training, may also be worth considering.)